# Can a function typedef be associated with extern "C"

Tags: c++, linkage

It is apparently legal to write:

```
extern "C" typedef int foo_func(int);
```

However, if I use this typedef to declare a function, like:

```
foo_func foo;
```

will `foo()` have C-linkage?

Answer (score 3):

There is an example in the standard (and [repeated on cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/language_linkage) that covers this.  The name `foo` will have C++ linkage, while its type is a C function.